# pass rownumber to remoteCommand using Primefaces

Tags: primefaces, row, xhtml

Context: xhtml, java, jBoss.

It's working, ok:

-inside `dataTable` tags-

```
<p:ajax event="rowEditInit" onComplete="nestedTableRefresh();" ... />
```

-beyond `dataTable` tags-

```
<p:remoteCommand name="nestedTableRefresh" update="form:view:person:1:address" ... />
```

Question:

How to pass row number to the `update` parameter content as `rownum` value / index of edited row  (where `rowIndexVar="rownum"` in the `dataTable`)?

Comment: One way could be using `rowIndexVar` or `f:setPropertyActionListener` to get row index and do the update server-side (`RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("...")`).

Comment: `f:setPropertyActionListener` ? I do not know how, but maybe  `update="@([id$=nestedTableRefreshId])"` inside  `ajax event="rowEditInit"` where `remoteCommand id=nestedTableRefreshId update="#{cntrl.getUpdateContentOfNestedTableRefresh}"` regards method on controller, that returns `"form:view:person:"+editedRowIndex+":address"`